# MYSQL only get entries which are not older than X days

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I fetch rows that are now older than three days?

The dates are stored in a format like this `2018-12-06` for the *6th of December 2018*

Comment: Hint:  use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: put you `ORDER BY id`  after WHEHE clause i.e `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATEDIFF(creation_date, ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, -3))  ORDER BY id DESC `

Comment: I get a syntax error, you can't have `AND` after `DESC`. Don't you get that error rather than no results?

Comment: I think he's already got the answer from comment..

Comment: @Emil I think you should take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Emil sounds gr8, best of luck :+ Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Emil https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751134 should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but you need something like this,

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE creation_date >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY) ORDER BY id DESC
```

For [mysql syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) and [date function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid condition. Try it like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM posts 
 where date(creation_date) >=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
 and date(creation_date) <=curdate()
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here I used `DATE_ADD` function to go back 3 days